# Lisp insertion sort -> defun span() function confusion

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, insertion-sort

I am trying to learn how lisp works. Below is a part of a insertion sort algorithm and I don't understand what it is doing as a whole. I kind of understand what predicate list is but not sure what it is checking. Could someone explain?

```
(defun span (predicate list)
  (let ((tail (member-if-not predicate list)))
    (values (ldiff list tail) tail)))
```

Comment: PREDICATE and LIST are the parameters of the function SPAN.

Answer (score 1):

`(member-if-not p l)` returns a tail of `l` beginning with the first element for which `p` is false.  So `(member-if-not #'evenp '(2 3 4))` is `(3 4)` (and this is `eq` to the `cdr` of the original list in this case).

If `l2` is a tail of `l1` then `(ldiff l1 l2)` returns a list of the elements of `l1` which precede it.

So

```
(let ((l '(2 3 4)))
  (let ((tail (member-if-not #'evenp l)))
    (values (ldiff l tail) tail)))
```

will return `(2)` and `(3 4)` (and the second value will be the `cdr` of the original list).